# Extract numbers from a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, match, extract

I'd like to extract the numbers from the following string via javascript/jquery:

```
"ch2sl4"
```

problem is that the string could also look like this:

```
"ch10sl4"
```

or this

```
"ch2sl10"
```

I'd like to store the 2 numbers in 2 variables.
Is there any way to use `match` so it extracts the numbers before and after `"sl"`? Would `match` even be the correct function to do the extraction?

Thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, `match` is the way to go:

```
var matches = str.match(/(\d+)sl(\d+)/);
var number1 = Number(matches[1]);
var number2 = Number(matches[2]);
```

Answer (score 8):

If the string is always going to look like this: *"ch[num1]sl[num2]"*, you can easily get the numbers without a regex like so:

```
var numbers = str.substr(2).split('sl');
//chop off leading ch---/\   /\-- use sl to split the string into 2 parts.
```

In the case of *"ch2sl4"*, `numbers` will look like this: `["2", "4"]`, coerce them to numbers like so: `var num1 = +(numbers[0])`, or `numbers.map(function(a){ return +(a);}`.

If the string parts are variable, this does it all in one fell swoop:

```
var str = 'ch2fsl4';
var numbers = str.match(/[0-9]+/g).map(function(n)
{//just coerce to numbers
    return +(n);
});
console.log(numbers);//[2,4]
```

Comment: thx for your answer. I figured it would be possible with `split()` too.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative just to show how things can be achieved in many different ways

```
var str = "ch2sl10";
var num1 = +(str.split("sl")[0].match(/\d+/));
var num2 = +(str.split("sl")[1].match(/\d+/));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code

```
var tz = "GMT-7";
var tzOff = tz.replace( /[^+-\d.]/g, '');
alert(parseInt(tzOff));
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words explaining why and how this code snippet does answer the OP question

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's use case. It will only extract a single number for a start