# iMacros: Extract numbers from a string

Tags: extract, imacros

If i have the following string.

```
dhs4dtgsf678ds6fsgfd
```

How can i use iMacros to extract all the numbers from this string?

I have found many tutorials for extracting text and images but can't find a single one that describes about numbers extraction.

Comment: Use JavaScript scripting. Then use this code to extract numbers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851934/extract-numbers-from-a-string-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Use [EVAL](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL), for example:

```
    SET !EXTRACT dhs4dtgsf678ds6fsgfd
    SET !VAR1 EVAL("var x=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; x=x.replace(/\\D/g,\"\");")
    PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

The result will be `46786`